# What do the parentheses around a function name mean?

Tags: c, function, parentheses

In one of my project source files, I found this C function definition:

```
int (foo) (int *bar)
{
    return foo (bar);
}
```

Note: there is no asterisk next to `foo`, so it's not a function pointer. Or is it?
What is going on here with the recursive call?

Comment: No, it is not a function pointer - it is still a regular function named foo.

Comment: Is this the complete function ?

Comment: do you have evidence that this function is used in a useful context?

Comment: ...looks like some dummy function that was perhaps just written to see if it compiles, in existing source, and should have been removed. I'd remove it (if that is what the function really does), since at best it will be infinite loop (I'm not sure if C compiler is allowed to optimize that tail call to jump), at worst stack overflow.

Comment: Parentheses in C declarations help to amke the language ambiguous. Quick, what is `a(b);`? Declaration of `b` as a variable of type `a`? Or a call to function `a` with argument `b`?  The difference is syntactic, and you cannot know which way to even parse it without looking up the declaration info of `a`; i.e. are those postfix function call parentheses, or optional parentheses around a declarator.

Comment: I was going to ask this very question. Why in the world is this deemed to be legal? That [this syntax is legal (ideone link)](http://ideone.com/kF8zYx) makes an absolute mess of my parser! My parser's only response is "Don't do that then".

Answer (score 345, accepted):

In the absence of any preprocessor stuff going on, `foo`'s signature is equivalent to

```
int foo (int *bar)
```

The only context in which I've seen people putting seemingly unnecessary parentheses around function names is when there are both a function and a function-like macro with the same name, and the programmer wants to prevent macro expansion.

This practice may seem a little odd at first, but the C library sets a precedent by [providing some macros and functions with identical names](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/159846/why-does-the-c-library-use-macros-and-functions-with-same-name).

One such function/macro pair is `isdigit()`. The library might define it as follows:

```
/* the macro */
#define isdigit(c) ...

/* the function */
int (isdigit)(int c) /* avoid the macro through the use of parentheses */
{
  return isdigit(c); /* use the macro */
}
```

Your function looks almost identical to the above, so I suspect this is what's going on in your code too.

Comment: That may be the case here as well; I didn't look for macros...
And I did not knew that macro expansion does not take place within parentheses, Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @user1859094: On second look, this is almost certainly what's going on in your code. The `foo(bar)` inside the function is using the corresponding macro.

Comment: @user1859094 macro expansion does take place within parentheses, but expansion of a function-like macro only takes place if the next token is a left parenthesis (C99, 6.10.3§10), thus `foo (int* bar)` would get replaced, but not `(foo) (int *bar)` (the next token after `foo` is `)`)

Comment: How would such a function be called? Would you call it with the parentheses as well? For example, would this work: `(isdigit)(5)`?

Comment: @Greg: Right, that's exactly how you'd call it.

Comment: @Greg: mainly you'd take the address of it and stick it in a function pointer to call later.  That's the main point of this technique -- you can define something as a macro in your library header and users can still take the address as if it was a function.

Comment: Gosh... macro's 20 years ago I have searched hours to find that missing parentheses on macro's cause division to return unexpected values.

Comment: It's worth noting that the definition in the question will work *only* if `foo` is defined as a macro. If it isn't, the `return` statement is infinitely recursive. It would probably benefit from `#ifdef foo`, though I'm not sure what it should do if `foo` *isn't* defined as a macro (perhaps a `#error`).

Comment: To make this answer a bit more complete, I think it would be beneficial to show how the macro and function is called.  This feature basically is useful when both a macro and function with the same name exists.  Thus when calling the function, you surround it parentheses so that you don't get unintended macro expansion, i.e. (idigit)(4) will call the function, not the macro.

Answer (score 38):

The parantheses don't change the declaration - it's still just defining an ordinary function called `foo`.

The reason that they have been used is almost certainly because there is a function-like macro called `foo` defined:

```
#define foo(x) ...
```

Using `(foo)` in the function declaration prevents this macro from being expanded here.  So what is likely happening is that a function `foo()` is being defined with its body being expanded from the function-like macro `foo`.

Comment: Nice deduction (though using parentheses for this purpose should be punishable by law).

Comment: @ugoren: using parens around the function name is about the only way to prevent a macro expansion for a function-like macro. At times it's a necessary tool.

Comment: @MichaelBurr, there's also the option of not having a macro and function with the same name. I know you can't always control everything, but if you reached this solution, I'd say something is very wrong.

Answer (score -2):

The parentheses are meaningless.
The code you show is nothing but an infinite recursion.

When defining a function pointer, you sometimes see strange parentheses that do mean something. But this isn't the case here.

Comment: Evidently not; the parentheses prevent macro expansion. See the accepted answer.

Comment: @Kevin, My answer is about the code shown, and is correct for it. In almost any C question here, assuming unknown preprocessor definitions can change everything. In this case, answers that consider the preprocessor are indeed better, but it doesn't make mine incorrect.