# examining C library: better C String library

Tags: c, string, strlen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do the parentheses around function name mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13600790/what-do-the-parentheses-around-function-name-mean)

As an exercise and a learning experience I decided to go through the source code of a C library called a better C library([linky](http://bstring.sourceforge.net/)) written by Paul Hsieh. I picked this project because the source looked very clean and organized, and seemed relatively short and easy to understand since it was dealing with strings. Also it was a good way to learn how portable code is written.

so I plan to post style/logic/c specific related question from this project in this post.
My first question is what is a point of calling strlen like so:

```
(strlen)((char *) buff->data)
```

instead of

```
strlen((char *) buff->data)
```

Thank you,