# Can the name of function and function-like macro be same?

Tags: c, macros

Can the name of function and function-like macro be same?
Wouldn't this cause any problem?

Comment: they could be the same.

Comment: This will cause lots of problems and confusion. Don't do this.

Comment: you could use #undef macro-name if you want to make sure the function is always called.

Comment: Read this also [What do the parentheses around a function name mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13600790/what-do-the-parentheses-around-a-function-name-mean)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They could be the same. Depending on how you use the name, either it gets replaced by preprocessor or not. For example

```
//silly but just for demonstration.
int addfive(int n)
{
    return n + 5;
}
#define addfive(n) ((n) + 5)

int main(void)
{
    int a;
    a = addfive(2); //macro
    a = (addfive)(2); //function
}
```

for ex. MS says that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa272055(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: I simply write this code and it fails to compile: `#include <stdio.h>
#define max(a,b) ((a > b) ? a : b)

int max(int a, int b)
{
 return ((a > b) ? a : b);
}

int main(){
 
    int a = 5, b = 3;
  printf("%d\n", max(a,b));

    return 0;
}
`

Comment: because #define is before function definition

Comment: +1 because I learned something new.  But please don't ever do this in real code.

Comment: @FredLarson, AhmedHandy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13600790/what-do-the-parentheses-around-a-function-name-mean

Comment: @msam it should work regardless of the compiler (given it's c90 compliant)

Comment: OK. So the extra paren along with function call (`a = (addfive)(2);`) does the magic here! o.O. +1. Thanks @GrijeshChauhan for the link.

Answer (score 1):

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Function-like-Macros.html#Function-like-Macros

Here you can see that calling the function, of which a macro with the same name exists, calls the macro instead :) 
For the gcc at least!

This would cause no problem, but quite some confusions. I wouldn't recommend this.

Answer (score 1):

I will explain via cases:
If you declared the function first then the function like macro second, macro will over take the function. i.e. it will be called always instead of the function.

```
//Function
double squar(double x)
{
    return x*x;
}

//Macro
#define squar(x) (x*x)
```

On the other hand if you declare the macro first then the function later, an exception will be arise, you wont be able to build

```
//Macro
#define squar(x) (x*x)

//Function
double squar(double x)
{
    return x*x;
}
```

At the end, in the first case, you still call the function like @Hayri Uğur Koltuk said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21555676/can-the-name-of-function-and-function-like-macro-be-same/21555786#21555786) in his answer by `(squar)(5)`