# Need guidance with aspects of strcpy in C

Tags: c, string, strcpy

This code is from strcpy in string.c
I am trying to understand a few of the features here:

```
 char *(strcpy)(char *restrict s1, const char *restrict s2)
 {
     char *dst = s1;
     const char *src = s2;
     while ((*dst++ = *src++) != '\0')
         ;
     return s1;
 }
```

What is going on in this while loop?

`(*dst++ = *src++)`

Thanks.

Comment: Detail "why they declare src a const char and not just a char"  --> `src` is not a `const char`.  `src` is a `const char *`.  `src` is a pointer.

Comment: (1) `(*dst++ = *src++)` copies one character from source to destination and advances both pointers, so the next time it will copy the next character. Since the result of the assignment is the value assigned, the loop will stop after it copies a NUL, which must be at the end of every string. (2a) So that if it is also a function-like macro, it won't get expanded. (2b) The return type is `char *` because it returns a pointer to a character array, aka a string. (3) To inform the world that it doesn't modify `src`. // Try to ask one question per post, and try to better explain your confusion.

Comment: but so is char *dst. So why use a const?

Comment: Because it does modify `dst`.

Comment: so rici, if I wanted to copy from one array to another, could I just say `while ((a++ = b++) != '\0') without the pointer references, outside of a function like this with an empty body, is that acceptable syntax? And perhaps more efficient than a for loop doing the same?

Comment: @AndrewB: No. Please reread the chapter in your C book about pointers.

Comment: Ok. I dont have a c book. I am learning from online classes and courses. This is just something no one has covered.

Comment: This one isn't awful: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Pointers_and_arrays#Pointers_and_Text_Strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(*dst++ = *src++)`

There is a lot going on here.
The first thing to note is that this is assigning the value of `*src++` to `*dst++`.
The asterisk dereferences both `dst++` and `src++`, so this is an assignment of one `char` to another. Note that the `++` operator has higher precedence than the `*` (dereference) operator. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence.

The second important detail is that the increments are postfix; `++` is to the right of the variables `dst` and `src`. So `dst` and `src` are only incremented after the check inside the while is complete. Effectively, this sets the first character in `dst` to be the first character in `src`.

So, `dst` and `src` increment by one each time the first character of `src` is not the zero character `\0`.

For your second question, see [What do the parentheses around a function name mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13600790/what-do-the-parentheses-around-a-function-name-mean).

`src` is declared a `const char *` because the character(s) it points to are not being modified and this is generally good practice. There are lots of discussions on this on the internet; e.g. https://dev.to/fenbf/please-declare-your-variables-as-const. Note that `src` itself (the pointer) is clearly modified in the while loop.